# jquery map - assign the return value as a key of the receiving object

Tags: jquery, dictionary

I have:

```
    <img class="images" src="src1">
    <img class="images" src="src2">
    <img class="images" src="src3">
    <img class="images" src="src4">

var pictures = $(".images").map(function(){
    return $(this).attr("src");
})
```

The code above creates a new pictures array. Can you think of an efficient way to create a new pictures object using the jQuery map function. I would like to do something like:

```
var pictures[key] = $(".images").map(function(){
    var key = $(this).attr("src");
    return key;
})
```

... directly assign the return value as a key to the pictures object. is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just iterate the collection?

```
var picObj = {};
$(".images").each(function() {
    picObj[$(this).attr("src")] = '...';
});
```

([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/6RVWh/) - will print to the `console`)

Comment: @Marcel `map` will always create an array. This is your *cool trick*.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand exactly what you are looking for but you could do something like this:

```
var pictures = [];

    $(".images").each(function(){
    var src = $(this).attr("src");
    var img = $('<img>', { src: src});
    pictures.push(img)

})
```

and pictures is an array of image objects

Comment: is that possible? i thought map is allways meant to return something ... in your example I could just replace map with each, couldnt I?

Comment: @Narcel You could. Using `map` here is completely meaningless and misleading.

Comment: @Marcel yes, maybe you should replace it with each! :)